# Stored Proceedure 1064 Error My SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

my first time using one of these and I'm pretty sure this works as I have picked it up on Stackoverflow how ever when I run it as an SQL command it fails. This seems to be a common problem and having tried several different sets of code I seem to get the same problem....

> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '$$ CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120),
>   coordinate2 VARCHAR(' at line 1

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetDistance`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate2 VARCHAR(120))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(120)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos_comma1, pos_comma2 INT;
    DECLARE lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, distance DECIMAL(18,12);
    select locate(',', coordinate1) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate1, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon1;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat2;
        select ((ACOS(SIN(lat1 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat2 * PI() / 180) + COS(lat1 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat2 * PI() / 180) * COS((lon1 - lon2) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) into distance;
    RETURN distance;
END$$
```

Thanks - Terran

EDIT

Tried..........

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetDistance`;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate2 VARCHAR(120))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(120)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos_comma1, pos_comma2 INT;
    DECLARE lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, distance DECIMAL(18,12);
    select locate(',', coordinate1) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate1, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon1;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat2;
        select ((ACOS(SIN(lat1 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat2 * PI() / 180) + COS(lat1 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat2 * PI() / 180) * COS((lon1 - lon2) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) into distance;
    RETURN distance;
END;
$$
```

and..........

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetDistance`;
$$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate2 VARCHAR(120))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(120)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos_comma1, pos_comma2 INT;
    DECLARE lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, distance DECIMAL(18,12);
    select locate(',', coordinate1) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate1, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon1;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat2;
        select ((ACOS(SIN(lat1 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat2 * PI() / 180) + COS(lat1 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat2 * PI() / 180) * COS((lon1 - lon2) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) into distance;
    RETURN distance;
END;
$$
```

Both fail....

Terran

EDIT - Found this working script.... LINK: http://datamoil.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/calculate-distance-between-two-points.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION distance_between (from_lat DECIMAL(6, 3), from_lng DECIMAL(6, 3), to_lat DECIMAL(6, 3), to_lng DECIMAL(6, 3)) RETURNS DECIMAL(11, 3)
RETURN 6371 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lat - from_lat)/2), 2) + POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lng - from_lng)/2), 2) * COS(RADIANS(from_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(to_lat))), SQRT(1 - POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lat - from_lat)/2), 2) + POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lng - from_lng)/2), 2) * COS(RADIANS(from_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(to_lat))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetDistance`;

delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`...
   ...
   RETURN distance;
END;
$$
```

Comment: @TerranBrown: I copied the first function from your edit and executed it. I got no errors.

Comment: I wonder if its some thing on my host stopping this then - retried and got "MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate' at line 1 "

Comment: @TerranBrown: I tried it on SQLFiddle.com and it does not work either. That is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your delimiter to $$ before executing this code.

This works for me (tested on MySql)

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetDistance`;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate2 VARCHAR(120))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(120)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos_comma1, pos_comma2 INT;
    DECLARE lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, distance DECIMAL(18,12);
    select locate(',', coordinate1) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate1, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon1;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate1, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as     DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2) into pos_comma1;
    select locate(',', coordinate2, pos_comma1+1) into pos_comma2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, 1, pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lon2;
    select CAST(substring(coordinate2, pos_comma1+1, pos_comma2-pos_comma1-1) as DECIMAL(18,12)) into lat2;
    select ((ACOS(SIN(lat1 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat2 * PI() / 180) + COS(lat1 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat2 * PI() / 180) * COS((lon1 - lon2) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) into distance;
    RETURN distance;
END;
$$
```